# margin-top is not working when i use clear:both

Tags: html, css

html,

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="left">left</div>
    <div id="right">right</div>
    <div id="bottom">bottom</div>    
</div>
```

css,

```
#content {
    border:1px solid black;
}
#content > div {
    height:100px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
#left {
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
    border-right:1px solid black;
}
#right {
    float:right;
    width: 50%;
}
#bottom {
    border-top:1px solid black;
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

demo

http://jsfiddle.net/saBE2/1/

i want to make some space, after left and right div in bottom div

but if i use clear:both, margin-top isn't working.

any good idea?

Comment: else you can simply use padding-top at the place of margin-top

Comment: Fiddle updated http://jsfiddle.net/saBE2/9/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clear floats after left,right.

Try:

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="left">left</div>
    <div id="right">right</div>
    <div class="clr"></div>
    <div id="bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#bottom {
    border-top:1px solid black;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.clr{clear: both;}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/saBE2/7/)

Comment: @Hardy thats what i am asking. elaborate where is the problem in my fiddle

Comment: @Hardy i think that is what needed. margin is clearly visible

Comment: sorry didn't see that content border.. my fault! That was actually just same code that i was trying in fiddle :)

Comment: @Hardy [with margin](http://jsfiddle.net/saBE2/7/) and [without margin](http://jsfiddle.net/saBE2/8/)

Comment: Thanks, now i can go home :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `clear` to clear foat like below

## css

```
.clear{height:0px !important;clear:both;margin:0 !important;padding:0 !important;}
```

## html

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="left">left</div>
    <div id="right">right</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="bottom">bottom</div>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rajniartoon/saBE2/6/)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your fiddle jsfiddle.net/saBE2/5/

The problem is that is doesn't look right with the margin because you don't have any border at the bottom for left and right boxes, also try and put margin under boxes left and right.

```
#content {
border:1px solid black;
}
#content > div {

box-sizing:border-box;
-moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
#left {
float:left;
width: 50%;
border-right:1px solid black;
border-bottom:1px solid black;
margin-bottom:50px;
}
#right {
float:left;
width: 50%;
clear:right;
border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
#bottom {
border-top:1px solid black;
clear: both;
margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right `clear:both;`. It's because `clear:both` makes the element drop below any floated elements that precede it in the document.

But if you make your div `display:inline-block` with cover `width:100%`. It's take margin.

[Try in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saBE2/10/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

1. Remove the float property from both the left and right divs.
2. Add display: inline-block property to both.

Now, the margin-top: 50px of bottom div will be applied.

Further, adjust the width of both divs, make them lesser than 50%, based on how much space you want to add around these divs.